# IDs for LoRa modules

Tags: arduino, lora, lorawan

I use two SX1278 LoRa Ra-02 modules for communication. I wonder how I can set IDs for these two modules to deny an interference with other LoRa modules which work at the same frequency.

I mean, is there a solution similar to pipe addresses of NRF24l01 communication.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to identify your own communication or identify separate nodes from each other? Do you want to make your communication unreadable by others?

Comment: I want to identify separate nodes from each other. Yes, I want it to be unreadable by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption is the answer to blocking snooping on your communication. This can be a basic [XOR encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher), a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) or even better [rsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

For the unique ID problem: there are several solutions to this problem and it highly depends on the specific microcontroller you are using. A solution was offered on [arduino.stackexchange.com](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/283/56652).

For example the ESP8266 has a unique ID accessible through this piece of code: `ESP.getChipId()`.

Another option which uses external hardware would be the [DS2401](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2401.pdf) from Maxim Integrated. This is a Silicon Serial Number chip accessible trough a one-wire interface.